# Qt QTextBrowser/QTextEdit: Tab key changes bullet/ordered list indentation

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, desktop-application, qt6

I am using C++ and Qt6 and I am creating a text editor that mimics basic functionality of Word or Evernote for those that use it.
I want when the user presses the key tab for this to happen:

[image]

The second bullet is what I am getting and the third bullet is what I want.

I have this code ready:

```
QTextCursor cursor = ui->textEditor->textCursor();
QTextList *currentList = cursor.currentList();

if(currentList)
{
    QTextListFormat listFormat;
    QTextListFormat::Style currentStyle = currentList->format().style();

    listFormat.setIndent(cursor.currentList()->format().indent() + increment);
    if (currentStyle == QTextListFormat::ListDisc || currentStyle == QTextListFormat::ListCircle || currentStyle == QTextListFormat::ListSquare)
    {
        if (listFormat.indent() == 1){listFormat.setStyle(QTextListFormat::ListDisc);}
        if (listFormat.indent() == 2){listFormat.setStyle(QTextListFormat::ListCircle);}
        if (listFormat.indent() >= 3){listFormat.setStyle(QTextListFormat::ListSquare);}
    }
    if (currentStyle == QTextListFormat::ListDecimal || currentStyle == QTextListFormat::ListUpperAlpha || currentStyle == QTextListFormat::ListLowerAlpha)
    {
        if (listFormat.indent() == 1){listFormat.setStyle(QTextListFormat::ListDecimal);}
        if (listFormat.indent() == 2){listFormat.setStyle(QTextListFormat::ListUpperAlpha);}
        if (listFormat.indent() >= 3){listFormat.setStyle(QTextListFormat::ListLowerAlpha);}
    }
    currentList->setFormat(listFormat);
}
else
{
    QTextBlockFormat blockFormat = cursor.block().blockFormat();
    blockFormat.setIndent( increment == 1 ? blockFormat.indent() + 1 : (blockFormat.indent() == 0 ? 0 : blockFormat.indent() - 1));
    cursor.setBlockFormat(blockFormat);
}
```

Is there a way I can change what the tab key does when pressed inside a focused QTextEdit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it!

I re-implemented the QMainWindow eventFilter for my class instance that inherits QMainWindow.

```
    bool SummaryWindow::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
{
    if (obj == ui->textEditor)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::KeyPress)
        {
            QKeyEvent *keyEvent = static_cast<QKeyEvent*>(event);
            if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Tab)
            {
                this->changeListIndentation(1);
                return true;
            }
            if (keyEvent->key() == Qt::Key_Backtab)
            {
                this->changeListIndentation(-1);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
        return QMainWindow::eventFilter(obj, event);
}
```

Using this method, I was able to connect the "Tab Key" to the slot I implement myself in the OP.

Finally:

```
ui->textEditor->installEventFilter(this);
```

Comment: Code is not really clean but I wanted to get the concept across.